# Can you make a function take more than one type in Elm? Can you have an overloaded function?

Tags: functional-programming, pattern-matching, overloading, elm

I'm trying to port a library from JS, and I've gotten to a function that can either take a string or a list of strings.  If given a string, it'll split it into a list of strings and then continue as if it had been passed that in the first place.

I can sort of do it by defining my own type, but it makes the API ugly and require a custom Type prefix your data.

Here's what I've got:

```
type DocumentBody = Raw String | Words List String

tokenize: DocumentBody -> List String
tokenize s = 
    case s of
        Raw str_body -> String.split " " str_body |> (List.map String.toLower)
        Words list_body -> List.map String.toLower list_body

-- Tests

tests = 
    suite "Tokenizer"
    [ test "simple" <| assertEqual ["this", "is", "a", "simple", "string"]
                                   <| tokenize (Raw "this is a simple string")

    , test "downcasing tokens: string" <| assertEqual ["foo", "bar"]
                                                      <| tokenize (Raw "FOO BAR")

    , test "downcasing tokens: list of str" <| assertEqual ["foo", "bar"]
                                                           <| tokenize (Words ["Foo", "BAR"])
    ]
```

Ultimately, I don't think that the port should support this kind of behavior, but how do you pattern match on just the enumerations of the type instead of needing the prefix `Raw` or `Words` in my example?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you cannot overload functions in elm the same way you can in other languages. Each function has a single signature. If you want a function to accept a parameter that can be of many types, your solution using a union type works just fine.

You say it makes the API ugly. I wouldn't call it ugly. Perhaps the syntax of the type declaration or case statements is unappealing but I say, give it time. It will grow on you. There's a lot of power and safety there. You're not letting the code make any assumptions, you are forced to handle every scenario, and it's one of the strengths of working in a language like elm.

Your pattern matching code is appropriate. You cannot shorten it beyond that.

At the same time, I can understand the pain of rewriting a javascript library and trying to communicate over ports from raw javascript. You're rewriting things in a much stricter language, and you won't be able to duplicate function signatures that in javascript, accepted anything and everything. But again, that's a strength of elm, not a weakness. Use the opportunity to tighten up the API and remove ambiguity.

When it comes to your specific example, to me it feels like there are a few possible alternatives beyond your solution. I'd argue that the `tokenize` function is promising too much to begin with; it's too ambiguous. When writing code in functional languages, I prefer to keep things small and composable. To me, it should really be two separate functions, each with a single, specific purpose.

Comment: "...you won't be able to duplicate function signatures..."  or rather, duplicate the complete lack of them ;)

Comment: to your point, now the caller needs to know what a `DocumentBody` is, since that is the type that this function takes and so it makes sense to expose the `Raw` and `Words` type prefixes to them

Comment: Right, and that's not something cleanly done over ports, so I'd lean towards splitting it out into separate functions.